# How to pipe STDERR to a file

Tags: file, pipe, stderr

A program have too many screen print out.

I want to save STDERR to a file (if save all STDOUT & STDERR, file will be too large)

As the same time, I still want to see STDOUT in screen.

How to pipe STDERR only to a file?

Answer (score 4):

You redirect STDERR as shown below:

```
yourCommand 2>fileName.txt
```

Comment: How to do if I want to see STDOUT in screen at the same time?

Comment: STDOUT is 1, and is not redirected in the example, so it comes to your screen automatically.